# 600 students and 240 lectures, every student has to visit at least 80 lectures. Show at least 40 lectures have been visited by at least 100 students.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

We have $600$ students and $240$ lectures. Every student has to visit at least $80$ lectures. I have to show that at least $40$ lectures have been visited by at least $100$ students.

$600 \cdot80 = 48000$ total visits have to be made. Let's put $99$ students into each lecture, so $99 \cdot 240 =23901$. $48000 - 23901 > 40$ and we are done.

This seemed too easy for me, is this really it already?

Comment: How is 99×240 not a multiple of 10?

Comment: The argument seems flawed, there can be 39 lectures with more than 100 students, but 99.240 means that the argument works only when atmost 240 lectures are attended by atmost 99 students, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea about using the visits is correct, but you have only shown that we may not only have 99 students in each lecture. Instead, suppose that the property does not hold. Then, $201$ lectures are limited to $99$ attendance, and the remaining 39 are limited by the $600$ total students, so we may have at most $600\times 39+201\times 99$ visits, which is less the $48,000$ total required.